# Difficulty overlaying pure CSS animations

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have borrowed a Venn animation from elsewhere and would like to place icons (ionicons via CSS class) within the Venn so that they animate in accordance with it.

I've tried numerous approaches, but the closest I've come so far to succeeding is to basically run two sets of animations, using the same parameters, one after the other in the code.

Whilst the animation is now the same for the symbols as well as the CSS circles, they do not occupy the same space and so do not overlay as I want. How can I achieve this, within the existing code set up? I've tried padding, margin etc but that skews the circular graphic.

Thank you.

The animation won't run in the Stack Overflow editor so please view on Codepen:
[Link to animation on Codepen.](https://codepen.io/thomasabishop/pen/rqmNwV)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fff 25%, #bbb 75%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.box {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
}
[class^='c'] {
  background-color: #0ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
}
.circle1 { /*blue*/
  background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
  animation: c1 2.5s ease 4 forwards;
}

/*.ion-code{
  animation: code-symbol 2.5s ease 4 forwards; 
  transform: translate(15%, -12%);
}*/

.circle2 { /*yellow*/
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
  animation: c2 2.5s ease 4 forwards ;
}
.circle3 {/*pink*/
  background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.5);
  animation: c3 2.5s ease 4 forwards ;
}
/*---------------------------------------C1-BLUE-*/

@keyframes c1 {
  0% {transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% {transform: translate(-25%, 25%); }
}

 /*@keyframes code-symbol {
   0% {transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% {transform: translate(-25%, 25%); }
}*/

/*---------------------------------------C2-YELLOW-*/

@keyframes c2 {
  from {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
            
  }
  to {

            
            transform: translate(0, -25%);
  }
}

/*---------------------------------------C3-PINK-*/

@keyframes c3 {
  from {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
           
    }
    to {

             transform: translate(25%, 25%);
  }
}

/*--------Symbol layer -----------*/

[class^='ion-'] {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 150vh;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
}

.ion-code { /*blue*/
  /*background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.5);*/
  animation: ion-code 2.5s ease 4 forwards;
  font-size: 4rem;

}

.ion-arrow-graph-up-right { /*yellow*/
 /* background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5); */
  animation: ion-arrow-graph-up-right 2.5s ease 4 forwards;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
.ion-ios-settings-strong {/*pink*/
/*  background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.5); */
  animation: ion-ios-settings-strong 2.5s ease 4 forwards;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
/*---------------------------------------C1-BLUE-*/

@keyframes ion-code {
  from {transform: translate(0, 0); }
  to {transform: translate(-25%, 25%); }
}

/*---------------------------------------C2-YELLOW-*/

@keyframes ion-arrow-graph-up-right {
  from {transform: translate(0, 0);}
  to {transform: translate(0, -25%);}
}

/*---------------------------------------C3-PINK-*/

@keyframes ion-ios-settings-strong {
  from {transform: translate(0, 0);}
    to {transform: translate(25%, 25%);}
}
```

```html
<body>  
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle1 ion-code" ></div>
  <div class="circle2 ion-arrow-graph-up-right"></div>
  <div class="circle3 ion-ios-settings-strong"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Chris W. Thank you very much this has sorted the problem. I appreciate you going to the trouble of making a new pen to demonstrate : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to target the `:before` pseudo element where the icons live in this example

[SEE CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/zmwGmV)

```
.circle1:before, .circle2:before, .circle3:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: You can also remove the animation on `.ion-code`, `.ion-arrow-graph-up-right` & `.ion-ios-settings-strong` as well as the duplicated `@keyframes`

Comment: Guys, any idea of how I could hide the symbols during the first 0.5s? If you look at the updated pen https://codepen.io/thomasabishop/pen/OBmNwj, they are kinda meshed into each other which is brief but a bit unsightly. I've tried adding opacity rules to the animation but had no luck - I'm not very experienced with animation.

Comment: @ChrisW. that is perfect. Would never have worked that out myself. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to use flexbox for this kind of centering:

```
[class*='ion-']:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xydGzK

Comment: Ya I avoid attribute selectors and things like flex just out of old habits when those sort of things became a performance consideration when overly-used back in the day. Just as valid of an answer though +1